# IP filter in Google Analytics is not working for internal site searches

Tags: search, google-analytics, ip-address, internals, google-analytics-filters

we have an IP filter set up to exclude internal traffic affecting our data. We use the basic set up which is working fine - Filter Type: Predefined > Exclude > traffic from the IP addresses > that are equal to > our fixed IP address.

However, all our internal site searches are still showing up as page views in Behaviour > Site Content & Site Search. For example, I can see this page in our reports:

*/search?keywords=xyz*

**How can we make the IP filter work properly and exclude internal site searches?**

Comment: Is the search page truly only accessible to internal users? Could a web crawler find it? Some additional things to note: IP filters (and all filters) are not retroactive - so they only prevent traffic from showing up if it occurred after the filter was set up - check the date range on the report you are pulling. Also, IP addresses are not always permanent and can change, depending on ISPs. Might be more reliable to just filter on the URL patterns you want to block.

Comment: @JoshuaT Thanks for your reply. The search page is open to the public. The date range is correct - I'm changing the report to the date I perform the internal site search tests and my test keywords (as written in the OP) are still showing up in the report. Our IP address is static.